# How to add a comparator to a custom sort function

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, c++14, comparator

So I've implemented merge sort which, for all intends and purposes, could also be a custom sort function and I've started turning it into a template function.

Where I've run into a problem is when I wanted to add to possibility of passing a custom compare function in order to sort in different ways. (eg. std::greater and std::less or any custom one).

I've verified that the sorting algorithm works when I'd replace the ints by T. How would I add the custom compare function from here in order to also sort custom objects etc?

```
template <  typename T, 
            class Compare>
void merge( vector<T> &arr, int start, int mid, int end, Compare comp ) 
{
    int lptr = start; 
    int rptr = mid+1; 
    int tempptr = 0; 

    vector<T> temp( end - start + 1 ); 

    for ( int i = 0; i<temp.size(); i++)
    {
        if ( lptr > mid ) //done with left-section, just move the right elements
        {   
            temp[tempptr] = arr[rptr];
            rptr++;
        } else if ( rptr > end ) //done with right-section, just move the left elements
        {
            temp[tempptr] = arr[lptr];
            lptr++; 
        } else if ( comp( arr[rptr], arr[lptr] )) // right item < left item, move right item
        {
            temp[tempptr] = arr[rptr]; 
            rptr++; 
        } else          //otherwise left item < right item, move left item
        {
            temp[tempptr] = arr[lptr];
            lptr++; 
        }
        tempptr++;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i<temp.size(); i++)
    {
        arr[start + i] = temp[i]; 
    }
}






template <  typename T, 
            class Compare>
void mergeSort( vector<T> &arr, int start, int end, Compare comp)
{   

    //if we're down to single elements, do nothing
    if ( start < end ){
        //call to right and left 'child' 
        int mid = (start + end) / 2; 

        mergeSort( arr, start, mid ); 
        mergeSort( arr, mid + 1, end );

        //call to merge
        merge( arr, start, mid, end ); 
    }
}



int main()
{   
    vector<float> arr = {7,8, 2, 6.6, 1, 4.1, 5, 3, 8, 9};
    cout << "before sorting:" << endl;
    for ( auto n : arr ) 
        cout << n << ", ";
    cout << endl;
    mergeSort( arr, 0, arr.size() - 1); 

    cout << "after sorting:" << endl;
    for ( auto n : arr ) 
        cout << n << ", ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0; 
};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A comparator implements strict weak ordering; to summarize it, the comparator implements the `<` comparison. So, all you have to do is: 1) Make all your comparisons as `<`, and 2) replace each comparison with a call to your comparator. Example: `lptr > mid` -- this becomes `mid < lptr`, and, of course, `comp(mid, lptr)`. Now, do the same for all other comparisons.

Comment: And propagate comparer in function call `mergeSort(arr, start, mid);` -> `mergeSort(arr, start, mid, comp);`.

Comment: And finally, you can add default type/value to your function:
`template <typename T, class Compare = std::less<T>> void mergeSort(vector<T> &arr, int start, int end, Compare comp = {})`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Your example is wrong, you do it for index comparison whereas only element of array comparison should use `comp`

Comment: @Bluefarmer, it looks like your code is already using `comp` correctly. Perhaps the only thing missing is to pass along `comp` in the call to `merge` inside `mergeSort` function.

Comment: Thanks for all the explanations. @Jarod42 is correct in that only the array elements need to be compared, the others are just index pointers. It seems the implementation was already correctly in place but I needed to pass along the comparator which I forgot. I will indicate Raxvan's post as the answer to this post as he answers the questions regarding custom object sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you have a `class or struct CustomType`

### Pre c++11

```
struct CustomCompare
{
    bool operator ()(const CustomType& a, const CustomType& b)
    {
        return a.Watever < b.Watever;
    }
};

//usage
merge(vector<CustomType> ..., CustomCompare());
```

### Post c++11, [using lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
auto CustomCompare = [](const CustomType & a,const CustomType& b)
{
    return a. .... ;
};
//usage
merge(vector<CustomType> ..., CustomCompare);
```

### There is third option:

You can use [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) but there must exist an `operator <` that takes your `CustomType` as arguments

Example:

```
struct CustomType
{
    //...
    bool operator < (const CustomType& other)const
    {
        return this->Whatever < other.Whatever;
    }
};
```

### And you can specialize `std::less`:

```
namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct less <CustomType>
    {
        bool operator()(const CustomType & a, const CustomType & b)
        {
            return ...
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `std::less` can also be specialized for `CustomType`.

Answer (score 1):

As Sam Varshavchik stated, replace your comparing operator with your comparing function. Meaning this:

```
 if ( lptr > mid ) //done with left-section, just move the
```

Changes to this:

```
       if ( comp(lptr,mid) ) //done with left-section, just move the
```

Btw you have a not handled case:

```
template <  typename T, 
            class Compare>
void mergeSort( vector<T> &arr, int start, int end, Compare comp)
{   

    //if we're down to single elements, do nothing
    if ( start < end ){
        //call to right and left 'child' 
        int mid = (start + end) / 2; 

        mergeSort( arr, start, mid ); 
        mergeSort( arr, mid + 1, end );

        //call to merge
        merge( arr, start, mid, end ); 
    }
    else{ throw "Not handled case";}
}
```

Comment: `lptr > mid` is index comparison, so should not rely on `comp`. `Compare` generally use `<` behavior, so reverse argument.

Comment: And your throw is wrong too, if range is empty, nothing to sort -> stop the reduction. early return would maybe be more explicit.

Comment: Since start and end are ints, the compiler would throw an error. Thank you for mentioning the compare.

Comment: *"Since `start` and `end` are `int`s, the compiler would throw an error."*. I don't understand what you mean. Your code throws (or even doesn't compile) for regular cases. OP currently correctly use `comp` in `merge`; just forgot to pass it as argument in `mergeSort`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating your implementation(s) for `merge` and `merge sort`. I've written the same function with 2 overloads and placed them in a namespace so that they don't conflict with the `std` library's version of `merge`. Take a look at my example to see what has been done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace test {

// without comp predicate
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt>
OutputIt merge( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                OutputIt d_first ) {

    for( ; first1 != last1; ++d_first ) {
        if( first2 == last2 ) {
            return std::copy( first1, last1, d_first );
        }
        if( *first2 < *first1 ) {
            *d_first = *first2;
            ++first2;
        } else {
            *d_first = *first1;
            ++first1;
        }
    }
    return std::copy( first2, last2, d_first );
}

// with comp predicate
template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2, class OutputIt, class Compare>
OutputIt merge( InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1,
                InputIt2 first2, InputIt2 last2,
                OutputIt d_first, Compare comp ) {

    for( ; first1 != last1; ++d_first ) {
        if( first2 == last2 ) {
            return std::copy( first1, last1, d_first );
        }
        // This is were I replaced the default `< operator` with the `Compare` predicate.
        if( comp( *first2, *first1 ) ) {
            *d_first = *first2;
            ++first2;
        } else {
            *d_first = *first1;
            ++first1;
        }
    }
    return std::copy( first2, last2, d_first );
}

} // namespace test
```

---

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1,3,5,7,9 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 2,4,6,8 };
    std::vector<int> v3;

    // print this way
    std::cout << "v1 : ";
    for( auto& v : v1 ) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    // or print this way
    std::cout << "v2 : ";
    std::copy( v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Merge without binary predicate comp function - functor etc.
    test::merge( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                 v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                 std::back_inserter( v3 ) );

    // using std's functors std::less - std::greater
    test::merge( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                 v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                 std::back_inserter( v3 ), 
                 std::less<int>() );

    test::merge( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                 v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                 std::back_inserter( v3 ), 
                 std::greater<int>() );

    // using lambda's as predicate compare objects.
    test::merge( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                 v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                 std::back_inserter( v3 ), 
                 []( auto&& a, auto&& b ) { return a < b; } );

    test::merge( v1.begin(), v1.end(), 
                 v2.begin(), v2.end(), 
                 std::back_inserter( v3 ), 
                 []( auto&& a, auto&& b ) { return a > b; } );    

    std::cout << "v3 : ";
    std::copy( v3.begin(), v3.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " " ) );
    std::cout << '\n';    

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to quit.\n";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

---

These 2 overload functions do exactly what you are looking for; to merge and sort while being able to choose what predicate comp function, functor, etc. to use in a single function.

Using the template `class InputIt` notation simplifies a lot of the internal parts of the functions; not having to keep track of `sizes`, `index positions`, `indexing into arrays`, etc.

All we really need to do is go through a for loop using the appropriate comparison operators on the `Input Iterators` then decide when to either use `std::copy(...)` or to assign an element from either `first2` or `first1` then increment our `iterator`.  Finally after the for loop finishes we want to use and return `std::copy(...)`. The first overload without the compare predicate by default uses the `< operator` where the second overload takes a predicate.

This also allows for you to pass any kind of container that has a `begin` and `end`, `iterator` making it very generic, modular and portable while trying to maintain the best practices of modern c++.